# How to implement Netlogo code for consensus

Tags: netlogo

I'm new in Netlogo can anyone guide me that how can I get a consensus of multiple turtles at the same point. I have a rough code in my mind but I don't know how to implement its NetLogo Code.

---

```
to setup 
  ca
  crt num-agents [ 
    set color red
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set shape "car"
    create-links-with other turtles
    ]
end

to go



  ask turtles [
    let closest-turtle min-one-of (other turtles) [distance myself ]
;    let difference subtract-headings heading (towards closest-turtle)
;    set heading (heading + 0.1 * difference)
;    fd 1

    let x-component sum [dx] of closest-turtle
    let y-component sum [dy] of closest-turtle
    move-to x-component
  ]
end

; Difference = Difference of my xy-cordinates from others turtles
; set_my_xy = [currentposition+0.1*difference]
; or [x;y]=[x:y]+0.1*sum[my_location - other_turtles_location]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? Consensus of what? What should the turtles do, precisely?

Comment: From what I can roughly figure out. You trying to implement the Viscek model right?

Comment: Yes I want the same Viscek's model, kindly can you provide me that code...???

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken you trying to implement something very similar to Viscek's model. Try the code below:

```
 ask turtles[ 
    set new-v-x mean [v-x] of (turtle-set other turtles in-radius <set-distance-for-vision>)
    set new-v-y mean [v-y] of (turtle-set other turtles in-radius <set-distance-for-vision>)
```

]

v-x and v-y  are updated as follows:

```
  set v-x speed * dx
  set v-y speed * dy
```

Comment: Yes I want the same Viscek's model, but kindly elaborate the about code or tell me in detail in the whole code.